# Task Parallel Library thread abort / interrupt

Tags: parallel-processing, task

Consider a large scale application that  uses a table in a 
sql server database to schedule jobs
Each row in the table is tagged with a queueID, a methodName and other meta data.
The methodName may be a native dot net interface, a legacy com local interface, 
a 3rd party com interface or URI to a 3rd party web service.

Currently there is a family of 32bit background exe's that process each queueID.
There is a set max time limit on how long each job can run set by the queueID, a watchdog will
kill the process if the time limit is exceeded.

We want to move this to a 64 bit environment & consolidate the multiple background exe process
into a single multi-threaded windows service.

The issue is how do we handle the kill of a job that exceeds the set time limit.
If we assign a task for each queueID from a Task Parallel Library from a single appDomain primary thread
Clearly net4.0 cancellation tokens cant be used since the thread may run a com interface or 
a 3rd party web service. If the appDomain watchdog task calls Thread.abort() it may corrupt the entire appDomain & tear down all task threads I am unclear if Thread.Interrupt() would reliably cancel a thread without appDomain corruption.

So what is the suggested technique to kill a thread that has exceeded the time limits?

OR

Do we just have the service create an AppDomain for each queueID then do 
myAppDomain1.ExecuteAssembly("queueProcess.exe arg1")
myAppDomain2.ExecuteAssembly("queueProcess.exe arg2")
...
almost the same arch that exists now but its a win service that controls the appDomains
and each queueProcess.exe & then use a the tpl thread pool do run the jobs in a set of smaller pools in each queueProcess.exe & the watch dog just does AppDomain?.Unload
when a process has exceeded its time limit

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call arbitrary native code and cause it to shutdown cleanly. If you kill its thread (which is possible if you have started that thread using CreateThread), you will generally leak memory, corrupt data, not release locks, keep file handles open and many more. This just does not work without cooperation. Processes are the correct way to handle this because they can be cleanly killed at any time.

For managed-only tasks you are safe with unloading the appdomain (ASP.NET does it that way). Don't just abort the thread because it might have left global structures in an inconsistent state. Or you might abort a static ctor which makes the entire class unusable forever (static ctors are not restartable).

You could have a generic host process which takes its input over a named pipe and runs your task. Such a process can be light-weight. You can kill it at any time.

Comment: hmm >For managed-only tasks you are safe with unloading the appdomain< are you sure 'managed-only' task since asp net can run non managed-only code via a com interface and that seems ok to be killed ?

Comment: If you abort a thread that is in com-code right now nothing will happen at first. The abort will happen the moment the call returns. This is safe if the calling managed code knows to dispose all native resources using finally-blocks. In a sense, this requires cooperation from the managed code being aborted. ASP.NET is actually taking some risk here. Can you audit your code to make sure native resources are released properly? If yes, you can safely do this.